# The existence of two maximal ideals with the same set of idempotents

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $A$ and $B$ be two proper ideals of $R$ such that $A+B=R$ and for each $r^2=r\in R$ we have either $r\not\in A$ or $r-1\not\in B$. How can we prove the existance of two maximal ideals $m_1$ and $m_2$ of $R$ such that $A\subseteq m_1$, $B\subseteq m_2$ and $\{r\in m_1\mid r^2=r\}=\{r\in m_2\mid r^2=r\}$?

Comment: Do you know this to be true, or are you conjecturing it?  If you know it, how?  If you are conjecturing it, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:  First, if $e$ is an idempotent in $A$, show that $B$ can be replaced with $B+Re$, and the hypotheses still holds.  Use this to reduce to the case that $A$ and $B$ contain the same idempotents.

Second, if $e$ is an idempotent of $R$ with $e,1-e\notin A$ (and hence also not in $B$) show that we can replace $A$ and $B$ with the new pair $A+Re$ and $B+Re$, still satisfying the same conditions.  Use this to reduce to the case that $A$ and $B$ contain the same idempotents, and either an idempotent or its complement belongs to $A$.

Now, extend to any maximal ideals containing $A$ and $B$, and note that a maximal ideal cannot contain an idempotent and its complement at the same time.

Comment: In the first case, in each step you use  an idempotent of $A$ to  make the  ideal $B+Re$. If the idempotents of $A$ that are not in $B$ are infinitely many , how does your argument work? The same question can be stated for the second case. Please, explain a little more>

Comment: As Keith mentioned, "satisfying the conditions" respects Zorn's lemma.  (Alternatively, you can just directly show that $B$ can be replaced by $B+\sum_e Re$ where the sum is over idempotents in $A$.)

Answer (score 3):

A proof by duality (to make it accurate first replace $A$ and $B$ with their radicals).

The dual statement about $X=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is that we have two closed sets $Y$, $Z$ with $Y\cap Z=\varnothing$ and, for any clopen $C$ of $X$, either $Y\nsubseteq C$ or $Z\nsubseteq(X\setminus C)$. The conclusion is there are closed points $y\in Y$, $z\in Z$ such that $y$ and $z$ cannot be separated by a clopen.

Indeed the hypothesis just means that $Y$ and $Z$ cannot be separated by clopens. Their images in $\pi_0(X)$ are closed subsets of a Stone space that cannot be separated by clopens, so must meet. This provides a connected closed set $T$ meeting both $Y$ and $Z$. Then take any closed points $y\in Y\cap T$, $z\in Z\cap T$.

**Remark.** Most likely spectrality can be substantially weakened here. We have only used that $X\to\pi_0(X)$ is closed, that $\pi_0(X)$ is zero-dimensional and normal, and that every closed set of $X$ contains a closed point.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add some detail to Pace's sketch.

Let's say that a pair $(A,B)$ of ideals of $R$
*satisfies the conditions* if

(i) $A$ and $B$ are proper,
(ii)  $A+B=R$,
(iii) there is no idempotent $e$ in $A$ whose complementary idempotent
$1-e$ lies in $B$.

[Before beginning, note that Condition (i) follows from
Condition (iii): using Condition (iii) and the fact that
both $A$ and $B$ contain $0$, derive that neither
$A$ nor $B$ can contain $1$.]

**Lemma.**
If $(A,B)$ satisfies the conditions and $e\in A$
is idempotent, then $(A,B+Re)$ satisfies the conditions.

**Pf.**
We establish Condition (iii) for $(A,B+Re)$
by reducing it to Condition (iii) for $(A,B)$.
Assume that $f$ is an idempotent
in $A$ whose complementary idempotent $1-f$
belongs to $B+Re$. Multiplying the expression
``$(1-f)\in B+Re$''
by $1-e$ yields that
$(1-e)(1-f)\in B(1-e)+Re(1-e)=B(1-e)\subseteq B$,
so the idempotent $(1-e)(1-f)$ belongs to $B$.
But now, since $e, f\in A$, we have that the idempotent
$1-(1-e)(1-f)=e+f-ef\in A$, while its complement
lies in $B$. This contradicts Condition (iii) for $(A,B)$.

Condition (ii) for $(A,B+Re)$ holds because $B+Re$
extends $B$. \\\

**Lemma.**
If $A$ and $B$ contain the same idempotents,
$(A,B)$ satisfies the conditions, and $e$
is an idempotent with $e, 1-e\notin A$,
then $(A+Re,B+Re)$ satisfies the conditions.

**Pf.**
Let me argue only Condition (iii),
since (i) is a consequence of (iii) and (ii)
is obvious here.

Assume that there is some idempotent $f\in A+Re$
whose complementary idempotent $1-f$ lies in $B+Re$.
Multiply the expressions
$f\in A+Re$
and
$(1-f)\in B+Re$
by $1-e$. We get
$(1-e)f\in A(1-e)+Re(1-e)=A(1-e)\subseteq A$,
and $(1-e)(1-f)\in B(1-e)\subseteq B$.
Now, since we have assumed that $A$ and $B$
contain the same idempotents, and the idempotent
$(1-e)f$ belongs to $A$, we must have $(1-e)f\in B$.
Since
both $(1-e)f, (1-e)(1-f)$ belong to $B$, the sum
$(1-e)f+(1-e)(1-f)=1-e$ belongs to $B$, contrary
to the assumptions of the lemma
($A$ and $B$ contain the same idempotents and $1-e\notin A$). \\\

Comment: Since the OP didn't include any details about the context or his own thoughts (it may even be homework, who knows), less detailed answers are probably preferable.

Comment: @Keith Kearnes: As  I commented above, how does your argument work in the second lemma when the set $\{e^2=e\in R\mid e\not\in A\text{ }\text{and} \text{ } 1-e\not\in A\}$ is an infinite set? your Lemma works for  finitely many steps! Please explain a little more.

Comment: @Antony: Use Zorn's Lemma. Order the pairs $(A,B)$ which satisfy the conditions by $(A,B)\sqsubseteq (X,Y)$ if $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$. This set is inductively ordered. Any $(A,B)$ satisfying the conditions can be extended to a maximal pair $(A',B')$ satisfying the conditions. Using Lemma 1, one can show that $A'$ and $B'$ have the same idempotents. Using Lemma 2, one can show that for any idempotent $e\in R$, either $e$ is in both $A'$ and $B'$ or $1-e$ is in both $A'$ and $B'$. Then, following Pace's sketch, if $(A',B')$ is a maximal pair, then $A'$ and $B'$ must be maximal ideals.